# Android jack and jill get stuck

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, circleci, android-jack-and-jill

I am trying to use Jack-Jill and Java8 for my Android app. Everything is good on my laptop but when I tried to run the project on CircleCI it's getting stuck on 
`transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug`

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply from: 'test-environment.gradle'



buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}



android {

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false        // true by default
        checkAllWarnings false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        ignoreWarnings true       // false by default
        quiet true                // false by default
    }


    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.projectname.android"
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        ndk{
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
}

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'com/androidquery/util/web_image.html'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/pom.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'org.bytedeco', module: 'javacpp-presets'
    }


    if (System.getenv("CIRCLE")) {
        defaultConfig {
            versionCode Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM"))
            versionName "1.0.30"
        }
    } else {
        defaultConfig {
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("../key.keystore")
            storePassword "key"
            keyAlias "key"
            keyPassword "key"
        }
        staging {
            storeFile file("../key.keystore")
            storePassword "key"
            keyAlias "key"
            keyPassword "key"
        }


        release {
            storeFile file("../key.keystore")
            storePassword "key"
            keyAlias "key"
            keyPassword "key"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ext.betaDistributionNotifications = false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable true
            proguardFile 'proguard-release.cfg'
            testProguardFile 'proguard-release.cfg'
            manifestPlaceholders = [providerSuffix: ".dev"]
        }
        staging {
            ext.betaDistributionEmailsFilePath = "staging_distribution_emails.txt"
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath = "release_notes.txt"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.staging
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled true
            jniDebuggable false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard-release.cfg'
            manifestPlaceholders = [providerSuffix: ".staging"]

        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            jniDebuggable false
            proguardFile 'proguard-release.cfg'

        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs  'src/main/libs'
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }

//    productFlavors {
//        all32 { minSdkVersion 15 }
//        all64 { minSdkVersion 21 }
//    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':libraries:Instagram')
    compile project(':libraries:librestreaming')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' + project.ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:' + project.ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
    compile 'com.android.support:design:' + project.ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:' + project.ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:' + project.ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:' + project.ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:' + project.GMS_VERSION
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:'  + project.GMS_VERSION
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.3'

    compile group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'converter-gson', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'logging-interceptor', version: '3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'hanks.xyz:smallbang-library:0.1.2'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.+"
    compile('com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    }
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.pubnub', name: 'pubnub', version: '4.0.11'
    compile ('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+') {
        exclude module: 'answers-shim'
    }

    // dagger2
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    // butterknife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

I use tool build gradle version 2.3.0-alpha1

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-alpha1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here is some of what it shows in the log console:

```
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug:app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
> Building 75%:app:generateDebugResources
> Building 75% > :app:mergeDebugResources:app:mergeDebugResources
> Building 75%> Building 76% > :app:processDebugResources:app:processDebugResources
> Building 76%:app:generateDebugSources
> Building 76% > :app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug:app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug
> Building 76%:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
> Building 77% > :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
> Building 77% > :app:transformJackWithJackForDebug
```

Seems that it's stuck like forever when it tried to do something with transformJackWithJackForDebug on 77% of building process and then it reached the build time limit (I set it as 60 mins )

Has anyone faced this problem before? Please suggest.

Comment: Happens to me too! Any updates @Jutikom ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653003/jack-compilation-stuck-with-androidstudio-2-3/42689736#42689736

Comment: Is it still an issue? Can you add your CircleCI config file, please?