# Jack compilation stuck with AndroidStudio 2.3

Tags: gradle, android-jack-and-jill, android-studio-2.3

I have upgraded my AndroidStudio today to latest stable version 2.3 (with gradle plugin 2.3.0 and gradle 3.3): now, I am not able to build my project which ran fine under AndroidStudio 2.2.3.

When I try, I am stuck at :app:transformJackWithJackForDebug as long as I don't kill my java platform process.

It is the same problem than [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828448/android-jack-and-jill-get-stuck) I guess but on stable release.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I killed many hours for the same issues after that i got link and its working fine at my end.

To use "Retrolambda" add few dependency.

1. dependency to your build.gradle file.

   classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0'
2. Added dependency into app/build.gradle file.

   apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
3. Please clean your build and run. it will work fine.

For more detail please visit below link:

1. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrolambda/article.html
2. https://barta.me/lambda-expressions-in-android/

all the best.

Comment: I don't want to use me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda again, I use Jack and Java 8 exactly to do without... which worked perfectly with Android Studio 2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

With Android Studio 3.0 (plugin 3.0) they are recommending to disable the Jack compiler as its been deprecated.